# vue transition-group - how to prevent both elements from reserving space in mode=out-in

Tags: css, vue.js, transition

how do I stop the entering element from being displayed until after the leaving element has left? (the problem with my attempt below is that the container must grow taller, allowing for both elements at the same time. But out-in was chosen to avoid this sort of collision)

```
        <div class="transition-wrapper">
            <transition-group mode="out-in" name="left-right-slide">
                <div class="panel-slot" key="left" v-if="slot === 'left'">
                    <slot :name="slot"></slot>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-slot" key="right" v-else>
                    <slot :name="slot"></slot>
                </div>
            </transition-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .left-right-slide-enter-active {
        transition: all .3s ease;
        transition-delay: .4s;
    }
    .left-right-slide-leave-active {
        transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
    }
    .left-right-slide-enter, .left-right-slide-leave-to {
        transform: translateX(100vw);
    }
```

Comment: final form working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/Log9auu6/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `<transition>` instead of `<transition-group>`. `<transition-group>` does not support the `mode` prop.